# how should i organize dll libraries in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, deployment, installation

i am try to develop a small application.
Now should i organize my 3rd party dll libraries so that when i publish the project and than install that application on another computer all the libraries should move with installer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what the bin folder is for. Just an FYI though, I've noticed DLLs not ending up there before and I'm like what did I do wrong?

1. Expand References in the Solution Explorer
2. Right-Click on your DLL and select properties
3. Make sure it says "Copy Local", I had one that wasn't showing up and it said false.